# connect to two networks simultaneously via single ethernet port?

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet, lan

Is it possible to create multiple connections with same port?
Is it possible to connect through them simultaneously/combine them?

P.S: I am on windows 10

Comment: short answer, no. Long answer, you can create teh network connections but only one will be used if both are valid for a given destination, they will not aggregate bandwidth for requests, or do anything else useful, unless they are actually acting as a router.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create multiple connections with same port?

With VLANs, it is.  This requires you have a switch/router that supports VLANs and that it is configured correctly.

> Is it possible to connect through them simultaneously/combine them?

- If by "combine them" you mean bonding or teaming, I think you can do that, but it'd be pointless.
- "Combining" two connections to two separate networks as in private networks doesn't make sense.  You have hosts that live in one network or the other, and sending traffic to a network that your destination host isn't on will not do anything useful.
- If by "network" you mean "path to Internet" - you cannot "combine" them unless you are working with a protocol that supports the notion of a single flow associated with multiple IPs.

  - TCP/IP does not.
  - SCTP does, but SCTP is a specialized protocol and you can't do the usual thing like browse websites, etc. with it.
  - If you can have two instances of an application working on a single dataset without conflict, you can then run two instances of that application, each sending/receiving from a separate IP.  Unless your application uses something like SQL to store data, it won't work.  You can't modify an existing application to work this way without a lot of work.
  - Specifically, Bittorrent won't work.
  - You *can* have an alternate path to the Internet available as a failover or backup in case the other path goes down, though.

Comment: by multiple connectionsd I mean giving multiple ips to the same ethernet port at the same time..is that doable somehow?